# How to use the size class adaptive layout in existing project

Tags: ios, xcode6gm, adaptive-ui

I have installed latest xcode6 GM. I have opened the existing project and changed it to use size class.
The problem i am facing is i have table view in which cell height is 50. While i run it different simulator, all have the same output. But when i create new project and all the cell are of same height, but in the existing the project cell height are differed.

How should i adapt the same height for cell using adaptive layout for existing project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the apps running in the compatibility mode, the size classes will not work.

Once you provide the launching image for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, then the size class will apply for your screen (If you implemented).

Also, you can still submit the apps without launching image for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, so that it will run in compatibility mode. Refer: [Can i still publish iOS apps without iPhone 6 launch images (apps that run in scale mode only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824333/can-i-still-publish-ios-apps-without-iphone-6-launch-images-apps-that-run-in-sc)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Wow, as an iOS Developer, I just wasted a couple of hours "discovering" this little gem.  I think it's completely unintuitive to check off size classes and then not see them! (unless you create the proper launch image).  Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      return 50;
}
```

I believe that's the proper way to set the height to a cell (unless you've got some custom cells in Interface Builder)

Comment: This doesn't make any change in height of cell for the existing project when changing it to adaptive layout.